# Set the node url the same as term url

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, tokens, path-aliases

It's enough for me to have taxonomy term page as node page.

I use Pathuato and Token to set auto Urls. For my node I choose token with term's path [node:field-tag:url:path].

But after creating a node I receive the node Url as **term-0** instead of **term**.

How to set the node url just as term url without any -0 or -1?

Comment: You can't have two entities addressed by the same URL...how would Drupal know which entity to serve when you visit the page?

Comment: good question...

Comment: I didn't created a page (like views page) for this vocabulary. That's why now Drupal cannot find a page with Url **term** but there is a page with url **term-0** and this is a page of my node.

Comment: Page for each term is created automatically. Do you have one node per each term? Do you want display node page when user addresses term page?

Comment: yes, I want one node per each term, other nodes have reference field to this node.